# Custom Gradle Properties not recognized

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, java-11

[image]

Unity in my device it not detected the custom Gradle Properties file, so it use the default JDK path of Unity. How to fix it? It still work in yesterday. And path of JDK 11 can't paste in Preferences -> External Tool.

Unity 2021.3.17f1
JDK required: JDK 11

I don't have anyway to fix it now.